# On change doesn't fire a 2nd time when element is dynamic

Tags: jquery, dynamic, element

I'm still learning JQuery and I hit a problem today that I didn't understand. I have some select dropdowns that get created in JQuery as part of a function, I then I want do something on the change of the dropdowns and after I'm done, run that function again (which will also re-create the dropdowns again). After those dropdowns are re-created, the on change won't fire again (in other words, it only works once).

If I put the < select > tags in the HTML and just do the options in JQuery it works, but clearly I'm doing something wrong and wanted to know what it is.

Here is something simple that I think shows what I mean. The console will get logged the 1st time but not any time after that.

TIA

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function toggle_test() {        
        // do other things
        var dt = '<select name="popdrop" id="popdrop" class="inspopulate"><option value="">Select</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="1">1</option></select>';
        $('#tt').html(dt);  
    }
    toggle_test();
    $(".inspopulate").change(function() {
        // do stuff and run toggle_test at the end
        console.log($(this).attr('id')+' changed!');
        toggle_test();
    });
});   
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<div id="tt"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Event handlers are bound to elements. When you replace the element, you lose the handler. You could bind the handler every time you create the element, but delegation would probably be easier here:

```
$(document).on('change', ".inspopulate", function() {
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, I think I know what you mean!